# .Net 4.0 C# - Adding to collections without manual loop

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'm new to the 4.0 framework (coming from 2.0), and I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this question so I figured it would be easiest to ask opposed to trying my luck with google.

Here's the scenario:

Let's say I have a collection of class "Wheel", and I have a second collection of class "Vehicle", where each vehicle object has a collection of "Wheel".  My objective is to add every Vehicle's Wheels to my Wheel collection.

With the extension methods, is there another way to do this:

```
foreach(Vehicle v in vehicles)
{
   wheels.AddRange(v.Wheels);
}
```

Or more specifically, in my actual use case there would only be one wheel (I need to add a specific member of each object in a collection to another collection):

```
foreach(Vehicle v in vehicles)
{
   wheels.Add(v.Wheel);
}
```

I realize doing the above is pretty simple in itself, but for this project I'd like to use the additions to 3.5/4.0 wherever possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A little bit of LINQ will do the trick

```
wheels.AddRange(vehicles.SelectMany(v => v.Wheels));
```

Thanks Fourth, I should point out the other case. If there is just one wheel then `Select` will work:

```
wheels.AddRange(vehicles.Select(v => v.Wheel));
```

Comment: or in the case of 1 wheel: vehicles.Select(v => v.Wheel)

Answer (score 4):

There is another approach:

```
vehicles.ForEach(v => { wheels.AddRange(v.Wheels); });
```

Or in case of one wheel:

```
vehicles.ForEach(v => { wheels.Add(v.Wheel); });
```